# Volumes of solids via rotation of regions between two 2D functions

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to see if Mathematica can simplify/automate finding the volume when the area between two 2D functions is rotated about an axis.

For example:  What is the volume of the solid when we rotate the region between
$$ y=2x  / and / y=x^2 $$ about the line $$x-axis (y=0)$$ .

Or rotate the region between:

$$y=x /and/ y=x^2-2x $$ about the line $$y=4$$

So the manual way is to plot these graphs, then find a ring in either x or y direction (difference between the 2 functions), then integrate that over the region, either with respect to x or y (depending on the rotation axis). Now can Mathematica somehow make this intuitive and make it 1-size-fits-all in a sense.

I have tried plotting the difference between both curves for both problems as such:

`Plot[2 x - x^2, {x, -3, 3}]`

and

`Plot[4 - x^2 + 2 x - 4 - x, {x, -3, 3}]`

Next these need to be rotated around their axis. No idea how.

Also would like to see a 3D plot of the regions as well.

-Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide Mathematica code!

Comment: I just plotted the graphs, was stuck on rotation and volume, nothing solid to have shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ImplicitRegion` :

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 <= Sqrt[y^2 + z^2] <= 2 x, {x, y, z}]
Volume[reg1]
(*(64 \[Pi])/15*)
```

or

```
NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, reg1]]
(*13.4041*)
```

similar evaluation for the second example:

```
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[4 - x < Sqrt[(y - 4)^2 + z^2] < 4 - x (x - 2), {x, y, z}]
NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, reg2]]
(*96.1327*)
```

Don't know why `Volume[reg2]` doesn't evaluate in the second example.

Comment: Hi @Ulrich Neumann: how are you getting the middle terms from? I noticed you always do Sqrt[(Y-M)^2 + Z^2] where M is the axis of rotation (about y=M) . Is this accurate? Why is that? How does Z fit in here? So I assume if I were to rotate about X=K, then I would have used Sqrt[(X-K)^2 + Z^2] ?